# MVC 4, user authorization using cookies

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, cookies, authorization

**[EDITED]**
Hi I'm developing a web project which includes *"user registration"* and *"log In"* sections.
I have my own *"USERS"* table in the database.

I need to know the best approach to:
**-** Implement cookies, to store users' information in their devices upon their *log in*.

**AND**

I have few information about this topic, and I wonder if `[Authorize]` filter action still does the job in authenticating and authorizing the user's access to certain controllers. having this in mind that in my case, I have a *USERS* table in the database.
Or is there anything I must do to make it work ?

Comment: If you are not using forms authentication, how are you obtaining user credentials to verify against your users table?

Comment: I might be wrong but my approach is: say each time the user requests a page, the corresponding controller will read the cookie, containing user's username for example, and verifies against the users table.
Is that a good approach ?

Comment: I just edited my question. I guess I could use Forms Authentication but I don't know how

Comment: Forms auth with a custom membership provider will do all of this for you.  See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f1kyba5e(v=vs.100).aspx